# What is the lowest noise power source?

Tags: power-supply

In particular two cases.

1) Unregulated: Supercap versus battery.

2) Regulated: Best regulation method to power precision low current analog circuits again with battery versus supercaps.

I know "best" is dependent on a lot of things. I'm looking for off the shelf linear regulator versus op-amp and precision reference, etc. I'm ignoring power supply and common mode rejection of the rest of the circuit at this point.

Comment: What kind of currents are we talking about here?

Comment: What's the bandwidth?  low noise near DC?, 1Hz? 1kHz? 1MHz?

Comment: Lets start in the 10mA range and bandwidth of 200 Hz for oversampled seismic data. Minimizing gain to take advantage of 22 bit ADC for best combination for low noise.

Comment: How much energy do you expect to draw? Are you ok with recharging the supercaps every few days? Batteries might hold for months/years. How long do you expect the circuit to run continously? In higher frequencys it might be more important how the battery/Scap, long wires etc.

Comment: @P.Koch I use an undamped seismometer and create a model of its behavior as a driven oscillator then integrate that for ground motion. So the initial application is to provide power if there is a larger power failure. As I was looking at the options I was struck that I have never seen anything about noise in batteries versus caps. Supercaps have not been around all that long, but it must have been analyzed. Assume current << than source can provide. If caps are better, the question becomes, should I always use a supercap in series with batteries or other power supply in sensitive circuits?

Comment: For opamp type supplies, the capacitance multiplier, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitance_multiplier#Transistor_based. is my favorite noise hammer.  The noise regection doesn't go down to low frequencies... but at low freq. the opamp PSRR is often good enough.  Or are you looking for a voltage source to drive a transducer?

Comment: Cooling the board will reduce noise over and above other things you do. Peltier elements are pretty inexpensive and can be used for cooling or use liquid nitrogen if peltiers are themselves noisy. But they can be on a isolated power source and and the cooling elements can be placed outside EMI/RFI shield. So I guess their noise won't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sensitive to ultra low noise then the actual series resistance of the power source comes into play.  A simple resistance can generate noise which is dependent on temperature.

At first I would assume that a perfect capacitor would have less resistive noise then a battery that has some value of internal resistance.  Supercaps may have some drawbacks in relation to internal resistance too, (you would need to check the actual specifications).

It turns out that even a capacitor can have some internal noise.  For some additional info see this wiki that includes calculations for both resistive noise and capacitive noise:   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise

But if you are taking this battery current or supercap current through a regulator it is most certain that the regulator will generate more noise than the battery/supercap.

Answer (score 0):

The 'best' solution would be to use a precision voltage reference. These are commonly available from multiple vendors (TI, Analog Devices, etc.) and typically can output up to 10mA. If you require additional current, then you can buffer this with a simple op-amp buffer.

Comment: Certainly true. But you bring us back to the original question. Do I get lower noise if I power the reference (and buffer) with batteries, or a supercap, or both?

Comment: Batteries / supercaps will have less noise, mainly because then there is no path for conducted noise to enter the unit.

Answer (score 0):

1) I would say supercaps in theory are better, but like Nedd says, in practice it depends on equivalent series resistance (ESR). How they each respond to EMI I don't know, but likely, the smaller the component geometry, the better, and you can add shielding, put it underground, etc... Then again you might not need to worry about battery vs supercap. What you want is proper decoupling as close as possible to where the supply voltage/current is used. Also consider the dielectric so your decoupling has a good response at HF, e.g. X7R capacitors work better at HF.

2) For low frequency noise current/voltage regulation, topologies based on JFETs are likely to be best. BJT is better at moderate frequencies and MOSFET at high frequencies.

Here's a suggestion for reading: [Motchenbacher and Connelly](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471577421)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I understand the low noise design. I'm trying to find if there is an real body of work on the noise of batteries versus supercaps. For example, batteries have the chemical reactions and accompanying heat. At very low currents, like femotamps where we need to use the electron statistics, the supercap is I assume pushing electrons. The battery reaction rate is getting so low that individual reactions can be counted and I would expect the chemical kinetics to add to the problem. Maybe this is a good research topic for as Masters Thesis or advanced undergrad project.

Comment: For an unspecific system as it is in this case, it makes more sense to think of the source noise as a noise voltage. The noise current depends on the load. Various caps and batteries may respond differently to temperature and pressure (which could be considered noise unless it's accounted for), so it's hard to say which is best.

Answer (score 0):

The best voltage source will be regulated with a home brew regulator based on a low noise amplifier, for instance the TI OP211.

Having decided on an amplifier, you then need a low noise reference to use with it.

At low offsets, up to a few Hz, a buried reference Zener specified for low noise is best.

Above a few Hz offset, a lead acid rechargable battery, at 50% state of charge, is reputed to beat out other batteries, and capacitors.

Use the buried reference to control your mean voltage, the lead acid to control your noise.

If this is too much engineering to achieve 'best' performance, then have a look at regulators from Analog Devices and Hittite, their low noise ones are astonishingly good, but still not as good as you could build from discretes!